# 'Failed to Parse Time String' Error In My Function To Find Difference Between Two Dates PHP

Tags: php, oop, datetime

I have not encountered an error like this before, until right now, and I was unable to find very much about it from researching the error.  Why would this happen?  And in my particular case, what am I doing wrong that is triggering this error?

```
 function datediff($date1, $date2){

                  $date1 = date('m-d-y');  
                  $date2 = date('m-d-y');  //To tell function these are dates

                  $sdate = new DateTime($date1); //error happens here
                  $edate = new DateTime($date2); //I did it this way because I wanted 
                                                 //it to be dynamic, not just a static
                                                 //date that had to be entered 
                                                 //within the function.

                  $interval = $sdate->diff($edate);   //Set difference = to variable

echo "Difference : " . $interval->m . " months, " . $interval->d." days, ".$interval->y." years "; 

  }
     datediff('1-21-1991', '12-14-2018');  //running function with my own dates
```

I already know an easier way to do this, but it's not dynamic and in an OOP approach, of which I am looking for it to be both of these things.  Any insight?

EDIT:  This is the exact error being returned:

"PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (12-14-18) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character in /workspace/Main.php:7
Stack trace:

0 /workspace/Main.php(7): DateTime->__construct('12-14-18')

1 /workspace/Main.php(13): datediff('12-14-18', '12-14-18')

2 {main}
  thrown in /workspace/Main.php on line 7"

Comment: So… you *have* or you *haven't* encountered this error? What input have you tested with? Why are `$date1` and `$date2` being overwritten by `date`?

Comment: Before right now, I have never encountered this error.

Comment: Yeah, "12-14-18" is a super ambiguous date. Even I wouldn't be sure what it means. Especially if it'd be something like "05-06-07".

Comment: That's why I am establishing at the top of the function 'm-d-y'.  It's not an ambiguous date... It's a legitamate date.  So what, some dates I am able to input and others I am not?  Is that what you're implying? That doesn't seem right to me.  Also, as you can see, I did not enter 12-14-18.  That is what is being returned to me.  I entered 12-14-2018.......

Comment: Uhm… `$date1 = date('m-d-y')` overwrites the value of `$date1` with today's date formatted as `m-d-y`. It doesn't matter what you input into your function, it's always being overwritten. And then you're trying to parse it again with `DateTime`. Probably you want [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is really your pointless use of the `date` functions, and that the date formats are not supported/expected. What you want is [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to explicitly tell `DateTime` what format your dates are in:

```
function datediff($date1, $date2){
    $sdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-m-Y', $date1);
    $edate = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-m-Y', $date2);
    $interval = $sdate->diff($edate);
    echo "Difference : ", $interval->m, " months, ", $interval->d, " days, ", $interval->y, " years "; 
}

datediff('1-21-1991', '12-14-2018');
```

Comment: createFromFormat was the best way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    $date1=date_create("2018-12-13");
$date2=date_create("2013-12-14");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
```

till not paplu return

Comment: `$date1 = date(...)` is still pointless, `strtotime` before `DateTime` is also pointless, as the `DateTime` constructor will already parse the data as `strtotime` would, and in fact passing a UNIX timestamp like that to the `DateTime` constructor won't work.

Comment: So what's the point of accepting `$date1` and `$date2` as parameters now; or alternatively, what's the point of those `date` functions?

Comment: Have you tried running this code? It still fails: https://3v4l.org/avenR

Answer (score 0):

it's the format of date you want to parse is wrong.
Check this:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php
i suggest to you to change from m-d-y in y-m-d format.
for example you can use this function to convert data

```
function convertDate($date){
      $date=explode("-",$date);
      return $date[2]."-".$date[1]."-".$date[0];
   }

   function datediff($date1, $date2){

                  $sdate = new DateTime(convertDate($date1)); //error happens here
                  $edate = new DateTime(convertDate($date2)); 
     ...
```

Comment: Using [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) instead would be a lot easier.